# Why am I receiving an unexpected remote rejection on Heroku?

Tags: git, heroku

I am attempting to run a web app with a Python back-end on Heroku. I am following the tutorial on the Heroku website, substituting their sample program for the one that I am trying to use.

I received this error unexpectedly despite having followed the instructions provided at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#deploy-the-app

```
remote:          Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement 
werkzeug.utils (from -r 
/tmp/build_76ae13b60ea2d97b6932e1f7934aba42/requirements.txt (line 4)) 
(from versions: )
remote:        No matching distribution found for werkzeug.utils (from -r 
/tmp/build_76ae13b60ea2d97b6932e1f7934aba42/requirements.txt (line 4))
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to stormy-everglades-84084.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/stormy-everglades-84084.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/stormy-everglades-84084.git'
```

What does this mean, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does installing dependencies from that `requirements.txt` file work locally? It's always a good idea to validate code in development if you can. I'm pretty sure you would have discovered this problem by running `pip install -r requirements.txt` on your development machine.

In any case, it looks like you're trying to install `werkzeug.utils`, but the package is actually just called [`Werkzeug`](https://pypi.org/project/Werkzeug/). Modify your `requirements.txt` to replace

```
werkzeug.utils
```

with

```
Werkzeug
```

then commit and push again.